# How to implement X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism in C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-chat

Currently I'm developing Facebook based desktop application.I want to integrate Facebook chat in my desktop application. I used Facebook Graph API in my application. So I want to use X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism to connect Facebook chat server.Anyone know how to integrate Facebook chat with X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Extended Permissions- xmpp-login, Here is the link  [xmpp-login](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/197155790399963/auth)

Comment: when I click your link,I got page not foound.please update link.

Comment: Actually, I try to click this link, It's okay!, This link go to Facebook developer page and Apps/Setting/Auth Dialog/

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/yourID/auth